# How to create a structure with fields from an array of strings in matlab?

Tags: matlab, struct

I have the following code, I'm trying to create an structure with field names from the cellarray of string.

data1 has the following data, it's a 5x4:

```
1   5    298      53
2   9    284      35
3   0    582      329
4   17   892      67
45  183  45       29

data1 = xlsread('data1.xlsx');
namesoftags = {'timeaxis','cputime','flux','volts'};
for i =1:4
    S = cell2struct(data1(:,i),namesoftags(i));
end
```

But it's giving this error:

```
Error using cell2struct
Unknown command option.

Error in structuredemo (line 4)
    S = cell2struct(data1(:,i),namesoftags(i));
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You a providing a matrix `data1(:,i)`, rather than a cell, to the `cell2struct` function. However, you don't need this function to accomplish your goal here. Use `S.(fieldname)` to build your structure instead.

```
data1 = xlsread('data1.xlsx');
namesoftags = {'timeaxis','cputime','flux','volts'};
for i =1:4
    S.(namesoftags{i}) = data1(:,i);
end

S = 

  struct with fields:

    timeaxis: [5×1 double]
     cputime: [5×1 double]
        flux: [5×1 double]
       volts: [5×1 double]
```

Comment: @LuisGarcia: If this answer helped you, please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/376604), so the question is marked as answered and so Matt gets a bit of rep for his efforts. You should also be able to upvote!